# What is better way to connect css

Tags: javascript, html, css, download

I'm trying to optimize some featuries on my website to make performance and make site loading faster. So the question is:

What is better way to connect CSS 
1) load all js and css on my hosting localy
or
2) use remote host connection links

For example:

1)`<link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

2)`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

And what characteristics does it affect?

Comment: I prefer local resources for the better performance.

Comment: This is a fairly opinion-based question, but I would go with #2 simply because CDNs are usually optimized for fast delivery time and users are more likely to have the stylesheet cached if it's used on other websites too.

Comment: first one is better

Comment: Does anybody know how works css and js delivery for online libraries and for local when they mentioned inside <head> tag or after footer section?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use Local Resources. It will give you a better performance

Answer (score -2):

If you have your webpage file on the same server/machine as the CSS resource,Local CSS resources will have a better performance due to the fact that when you go out on and get them from an external source, your website now has to load it, so it is like loading the webpage, then the webpage going, getting it, and loading it[the CSS]. It takes 2 times as long and has a higher chance of not working due to one server not responding etc.. Locally, the webpage doesn't have to leave the server to go get something, so all it has to do is load it. Overall, in my experience, local resources are the better way to go.

Comment: *"Locally, the webpage doesn't have to leave the server to go get something"* - The OP isn't talking about having the resources on the same machine as the browser, they're talking about hosting all of their website's resources on their own server versus using some combination of CDNs. So the browser will have to make http requests to *some* server for each resource...

Comment: I know, but if he has the webpage file on the same server then it is _**less**_ getting CSS to do

Comment: But before this topic i thought that server gives links to the client browser, and then browser dowload  all the libraries, while not asking again to the website, just bypassing.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes, I mean using not only CDN bootstrap, but also jquery libraries and others. There are a lot off useful libraries in internet. So i still don't understand the technology how works delivering proccess of  online based css or js and local